# SWIFT: Why is my semaphore not working?

Tags: swift

I'll be the first to admit I am new to semaphores.  However, I have looked at this block of code for hours and it's time for additional sets of eyes.   For some reason the "dispatch_semaphore_signal" is never hit, thus pausing my app indefinitely. I have used semaphores in other view controller successfully, but for some reason this one is not working.  Any ideas?

```
    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)


    _ = deviceSession.dataTaskWithRequest(deviceRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        if (dataString?.rangeOfString("HTTP Status 403").location != NSNotFound){
            print("Access Was Denied")
        } else{
            let deviceListParser = NSXMLParser(data: data!)
            let deviceListParserDelegate = DeviceListParser()
            deviceListParser.delegate = deviceListParserDelegate
            deviceListParser.parse()
        }
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
    }).resume()

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Forget the semaphore and put the line to reload the table view into the completion handler. Semaphores to work around asynchronous tasks is pretty bad programming habit.

Comment: Hi Vadian, I tried that with no success before posting this.  My table loads with no values.  Then if you scroll the values off screen they populate when they come back into focus.

Comment: Then the semaphore won't solve the problem either. I'm not familiar with `NSXMLParser` but if this class also works asynchronously reload the table view in the delegate method which indicates *didFinish*.

Comment: What do you mean by the delegate method.  Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: You're setting the delegate of `deviceListParser` to a custom delegate class so apparently this class provides delegate methods which are called at particular stages of the parsing process.

Comment: Right, but how would I reload the table from there?  Is that possible?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea about the contents of the class but maybe there is a method *parserDidFinish* or something similar. Implement this method and reload the table view there. Why do you implement the delegate class but do not use it?

Comment: There is, that's not the problem.  I just don't know how to reload a table on another view controller from there.  I can do some digging unless you have a quick tip.

Comment: Sorry, but the code snippet is too small to be able to judge that. The usual ways are  protocol/delegate or closure/block or – in case the view controllers are not related to each other  – `NSNotification`.

Comment: Hi Vadian.  I ended up fixing this with the NSNotification service, thanks for the tip!  Would you like to put that as the solution and I'll mark it correct?  Or I can type up what I did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116144/discussion-between-ged125-and-vadian).

Comment: `NSNotification` is always the easiest solution but it's supposed only to be used if the sender and receiver are not related – that means contiguous in the view hierarchy – at all. Your code snippet doesn't say anything about the relationship between the controllers, so I don't know if it's **the** solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this based on Vadian's suggestion to use NSNotification.  In the parser "parserDidEndDocument" function I added:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("load", object: nil)
```

And on the table view controller I added the following to "viewDidLoad":

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(loadTable), name:"load", object: nil)
```

Works like a charm, and this is a feature I'm sure I will be using a lot of in the future.  Thanks Vadian!